# how to let user choose the x_var in Shiny plot?

Tags: r, shiny

```
TD <- thyroid

library(readxl)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinythemes)
library(DT)

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("xaxis", "Choose a x variable", choices = names(TD)),
    actionButton("goButton","Update")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel('Plot', plotOutput("plot1"))
    ))
)
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){

  x_var<- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$xaxis
  })
  

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    x <- x_var()
    x
    
    p <- ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(TD$x_var, fill = TD$ThryroidClass))
    p  #+ 
      #theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=20))
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

The problem is in the `TD$x_var`. I wanna refer to the variable selected from the selectInput
but with this code I get
"Erroe[object object]."

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `renderPlot`, `x_var()` is already assigned to `x`.  So, we call `x` instead of `x_var`.  Also, to evaluate the object, we may use `[[` instead of `$`

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    x <- x_var()
    x
    
    p <- ggplot() +
      geom_bar(aes(TD[[x]], fill = TD$ThryroidClass))
    p  #+ 
      #theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=20))
  })
})
```

Or instead of extracting the column, use unquoted column  names after specifying the `data`.  This will also correctly name the legend

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    x <- x_var()
    x
    
    p <- ggplot(TD) +
      geom_bar(aes(.data[[x]], fill =ThryroidClass))
    p  #+ 
      #theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=20))
  })
})
```

-using a reproducible example with `iris`

```
TD <- iris

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Test App"),
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("xaxis", "Choose a x variable", choices = names(TD)[1:4]),
    actionButton("goButton","Update")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel('Plot', plotOutput("plot1"))
    ))
)
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){
  
  x_var<- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    input$xaxis
  })
  
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    x <- x_var()
    
    
    p <- ggplot(TD) +
      geom_bar(aes(.data[[x]], fill =Species))
    p
    
  })
})

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

-output

[image]